# Get observable from model in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an input in an Angular 2 component

```
<input [(ngModel)]="title"></input>
```

How can I get an observable for when the user changes the model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `ngModelChange` event this way:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="title" (ngModelChange)="someMethod($event)"></input>
```

In the sample the `someMethod` method will be called when the model is updated. The `$event` object will contain the new value.

You can only get an observable with controls (`ngControl` or `ngFormControl`):

```
this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  (...)
});
```

If you want to leverage observable with ngModel you need to implement it be your own:

```
titleUpdated$:Subject<string> = new Subject();

someMethod(val) {
  this.titleUpdated$.next(val);
}
```

Comment: Ok. How can I get an observable from calling `someMethod($event)`?

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why they did this. It seems highly inefficient.

Comment: You're welcome! In fact the approach is to use a control on a form element to do your use case ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't really need a model for whatever reason, I will propose you another solution.

I mean if you don't want to use template or reactive form, you could use something like in you component

*.html

```
<input (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value);">
```

*.ts

```
............................
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

............................
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

............................

constructor(){}

............................

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTerm$
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```